# How to specify 2-D coordinates of an object in matlab?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, video-processing, matlab-cvst

This is the scenario: I marked two axes (figure below) on a board and a camera(global vision system) sees the board. I want to make the vision system to recognize $X$ and $Y$ axes and specify coordinates of an object (preferably a colored one )in the form of $(x,y)$. How can I do that? is there any functionality in matlab to help me?
[image]

Comment: Your axes only have an origin, and no ticks. So the $(x,y)$ will be relative to the image space

Comment: @LaurentDuval, How it could be simplified?Do ticks work?

Comment: Just to be sure: do you want all the $(x,y)$ defining the grey disk?

Comment: @LaurentDuval,In fact it's an object to be grabbed by a robotic arm,e.g. a ball. So I think the centroid points may be enough.

Comment: You need also to define the length of the arrows or something that will give the scaling.